# How do I interpret the columns of the CPU window's disassembly pane?

Tags: delphi, assembly, compiler-construction, cpu-registers

There is a tool called the CPU window, which I get pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, that shows the disassembly of my code.

A green arrow to the left of the memory address indicates the location of the current execution point, then there is the memory addresses, but what does the second column mean, and why does the compiler sometimes jump more than one address after an instruction?

For example:

```
|first column|second column|assembly|
004520F4 55             push ebp      //continuous 
004520F5 8BEC           mov ebp, esp  //jumps to F7
004520F7 6A00           push $00      //jumps to F9
004520F9 53             push ebx      //continuous
004520FA 33D2           xor edx,edx
```

Comment: Opcodes. See f.i. http://sparksandflames.com/files/x86InstructionChart.html

Comment: Nice, what about the jumping, there is some kind of instruction size?

Comment: See also documentation, [`Disassembly pane`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Disassembly_pane).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's look at the code:

```
004520F4 55             push ebp      
004520F5 8BEC           mov ebp, esp  
004520F7 6A00           push $00      
004520F9 53             push ebx      
004520FA 33D2           xor edx,edx
```

Each line here represent a single machine instruction. The information presented is as follows:

- The first column is the address at which the instruction starts, displayed in hex.
- The second column is the machine code for the instruction, displayed in hex.
- The third column is the instruction disassembled to assembler language.

So the second and third columns represent the exact same information. The third column is provided to make the code more understandable.

Note that different instructions have different lengths. The first and fourth instructions are only a single byte long. The others are two bytes long. And that explains why the instruction address increments by more than a single byte following two byte instructions.

There are instructions that can take even more than two bytes and so you can have increments of 3, 4 and so on for such instructions. A good example would be call or jump instructions which encode the target address or offset. So, an absolute jump on a 32 bit machine might be encoded in 5 bytes, one for the opcode and four for the address.

Back in the good old days, long before I was even born, programmers didn't even have assemblers and wrote code directly in machine instructions. That must have been a whole load of fun!

Comment: Are they two byte because the opcodes is double (4 characters instead of 2) or is just coincidence?

Comment: The machine code is displayed in hex. So, 4 characters of hex represents two bytes. The machine doesn't store hex. It just stores plain old 8 bit bytes. So look at `8BEC`. That is two bytes long. When written out in hex it takes 4 characters.

Comment: @David - Yes it was fun, but '3rd Generation Languages', as we used to call them, are just as much hard work.

Comment: Imagine what a bonus it was moving from punch-cards ...  Drop a bunch of those and you have a REAL debugging task to get your teeth into :)

Comment: @Hugh been there, done that, spent the night getting them back in sequence.

Comment: @Keith - Now that's what I call OLD ;)

Comment: @KeithMiller, remember getting the cards back the day after, syntax error on 2nd card. Could take a week to compile and run.

Comment: @LU RD, and no internet to while away the time waiting for the printout to come back! Tell that to the youth of today and they won't believe you.

Comment: Punch cards? You were lucky!

Comment: And before punch cards, paper tape (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punched_tape). Fed through a teletype (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:ASR-33_Teletype_terminal_IMG_1658.jpg) with a rotating cylindrical head with a 'hammer' banging against its backside to force the character on the front to print on pin-feed paper.

Answer (score 2):

The assembly listing (third column) is the human readable form of the actual machine code that is in the second column, which the cpu is actually executing.

If by "*jumping some addresses*" you mean that the addresses in the first column don't always increment by one, that's because instructions have varying lengths in machine code. For example the first line, `push ebp` is a single byte with value `0x55` thus next address is just one more. But machine code for the second instruction, `mov ebp, esp` is two bytes (`0x8b 0xec`) hence the address increments by two.