# What are the items on the right of 'RIP' returned by uf command

Tags: assembly, x86-64, disassembly

For example

0:000> uf main
fun0!main [C:\cases\fun0.cpp @ 7]:

```
7 00007ff7`72536b90 4883ec28        sub     rsp,28h
8 00007ff7`72536b94 e85aa7ffff      call    fun0!ILT+750(?test1YAXXZ) (00007ff7`725312f3)
9 00007ff7`72536b99 33c0            xor     eax,eax
9 00007ff7`72536b9b 4883c428        add     rsp,28h
9 00007ff7`72536b9f c3              ret
```

[image]

Comment: hexdump of the machine-code.

Comment: not an *exact* duplicate; this is a different disassembler that doesn't leave spaces between bytes of hexdump.  But close enough.

Comment: You might also be interested in [What is the actual relation between assembly, machine code, bytecode, and opcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27629390/547981) and [How do I interpret the columns of the CPU window's disassembly pane?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17108127/547981)